# PHP re-ordering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am customizing my checkout in WooCommerce.

Currently, I want to re-order the shipping fields to be shown right after the payment, not in the summary.

[image]

as you can see in the bottom picture, I tried to move it with jQuery, 
`jQuery("#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.woocommerce-shipping-totals.shipping").appendTo("#payment > ul");`

which unfortunately works only when I am pasting it into the developers console, it doesn't work when I apply the script to pure JS content windows, in WP page editor.

It is an tr tag.
[image]

I was trying to move it in functions.php, with PHP, but I managed to mess up the whole website and had to built it all over again. So I figured I would ask for help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your jquery approach I think maybe the problem is that the page is not fully loaded when that JS is being executed. Your code should be something like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#order_review > table > tfoot > tr.woocommerce-shipping-totals.shipping").appendTo("#payment > ul");
});
```

If you want to do this in PHP, I think this [link](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/reorder-checkout-fields.html#move_between_groups) could help. As I found you want to move one field to another field group which can be done like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'misha_billing_email_another_group' );

function misha_billing_email_another_group( $checkout_fields ){

    // 1. We assign a field array to another group here
    $checkout_fields['order']['billing_email'] = $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_email'];

    // 2. Remove a field from a previous location
    unset( $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_email'] );

    return $checkout_fields;

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response

regarding the javascript, I actually have another one fired up into the same page.

`jQuery("#order_review_heading").insertBefore("#order_review > table");`
- this one add the h3 which containts the words "your order" before the order summary and it works just fine.

But the other one, I tried your method also just cant get activated no idea why.

Regarding the PHP, I looked it up, went through the tutorial, it is only for the input fields and there it quits. I cannot get the "hook" for the tr tag which contains the selection I need to move.

Comment: aww I guess it it is worth metioning that I have another js, which is hiding the element in which the position should be changed until on input field has enough text in it to be shown.


`jQuery(document).on('keydown',"#billing_email",function(){
     var val = jQuery(this).val();
     if(val.length < 6)
     {
          jQuery("#order_review").hide(2000);
          jQuery('#order_review').css('display','none')
     }
     else
     {
          jQuery("#order_review").show(2000);
          jQuery('#order_review').css('display','grid')

     }

 });`

Comment: So I think I didn't get the problem right. Sorry, I don't have ideas on your case.

Comment: I'm 90% certain you should do this with PHP and not JS. Erfan's `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter is the direction I'd take.